Search for a specific contact attribute API REST On Marketing cloud
I'm trying to find some contacts attributes of an specific contact (in the example Contact Key 123).
But I'm not able to run the payload. Getting 400 Bad Request
endpoint https://{{et_subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/contacts/v1/attributes/search
{
    "request": {
        "attributes": [{
                "key": "Email Addresses.Email Address"
            },
            {
                "key": "MobileConnect Demographics.Mobile Number"
            }]

    }"conditionSet": {
    "operator": "And",
    "conditionSets": [],
    "conditions": [{
        "attribute": {
            "key": "Contact.Contact Key",
            
            
        },
            "operator": "Equals",
            "value": {
                "items": ["123"]
        }
    }]
}

Could someone help me, please?

}"conditionSet": {-
this line is missing a comma; "key": "Contact.Contact Key", - this line has a comma too many; your JSON is missing the closing }
